# Loop to generate string and variables

Tags: r, string

I have a set of confusionMatrixes of 100 models like wynik1, ... wynik100.

I want to have a vector of accuracies of all of these models.

I have written a loop, but it does not work.

Where is the problem?

The task is to generate strings and variables from the strings:

```
confusionMatrix(m2pred,cats$Sex)-> wynik1
...

accuracy <- NULL
b_accuracy <- NULL
for (i in 1:100){
  name <- paste0("wynik",i)
  ac<- name$overall[1]
  bac<- name$byClass[11]
  accuracy <- c(accuracy, ac)
  b_accuracy <- c(b_accuracy, bac)
}
accuracy
```

The output is:

> ```
> Error in nazwa$overall : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> > accuracy
> NULL
> ```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example and precisely define what are inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: `name` is a character value, not a confusion matrix.  Perhaps you meant `name <- get(paste0("wynik",i))`?

Comment: @Benjamin - yes, exactly! Thanks. You can answer if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`name` is a character object, and not a confusion matrix.  You should use `get`

```
confusionMatrix(m2pred,cats$Sex)-> wynik1
...
accuracy <- NULL
b_accuracy <- NULL
for (i in 1:100){
  name <- get(paste0("wynik",i))
  ac<- name$overall[1]
  bac<- name$byClass[11]
  accuracy <- c(accuracy, ac)
  b_accuracy <- c(b_accuracy, bac)
}
accuracy
```

But the `for` loop here is a convoluted way to get the information you are after.  Also, you are growing (changing the length on each iteration) `accuracy` and `b_accuracy`, which isn't recommended. I might recommend the following, which puts all of your confusion matrices into a list and then uses an `*apply` function to extract the pieces you want into a vector.

```
wynik_list <- 
  mget(x = paste0("wynik_", 1:100))

accuracy <- 
  sapply(wynik_list,
         function(x) x$overall[1])

b_accuracy <- 
  sapply(wynik_list,
         function(x) x$byClass[11])
```